# Project Properties Windows Blank in Visual Studio 2022 Community 17.1.0

Tags: properties, project, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to access the project properties but the window appears blank. I've tried web solutions View>Properties Window, f4, right click on project folder>properties, Also tried resetting import/export settings, searching for specific tab

everything results in a blank window.. Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have noted this behavior in multiple other windows in VS 2019 and 2022.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this same problem with VS 2022 v17.4.0 Preview 1.0 in a C# Windows forms app.  Closing and opening the solution/VS didn't have any effect.

After I closed all the open tabs and reopened a file, the Properties pane was populating correctly.

**Edit:** After closing tabs and opening the properties if its still blank move the Window and it shows!

Comment: worked for me as well.

Comment: closing all open tabs worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Going away on another opened tab and coming back starts populating properties window.

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.5.3

Comment: I can verify that this works. Unfortunately, the behavior extends to project/solution/file history and other windows as well. Same behavior in 2019.

Comment: This has worked for me on several occasions. Click on a control - no properties visible. Click another tab and come back - properties visible.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to consistently reproduce the bug by double clicking the Build Action value.
This was making the content of the Properties Window to disappear.
To work around it, I've created a new "abc.json" file and set the values of Build Action and Copy to Output Directory from the dropdown.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me - see my response https://stackoverflow.com/a/77233692/1001392

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me when I double clicked on the Build Action property.

I finally opened the project file in a text editor and noticed that the XML defining that file in an item group started with "Page" instead of "None".

```
<Page Include="myFile.txt" />
```

instead of

```
<None Remove="myFile.txt" />
```

Manually editing the project file back to "None" fixed the problem.

Seems that the root cause is that double clicking automatically selects the next option in the Build Action list, and the next option is "Page".

Answer (score 0):

Does your toolbox items also appear 'greyed out'?

Try Going to your Build Menu and select

Clean Solution

(and perhaps Rebuild afterward - or not)

Answer (score 0):

This happens constantly on my install. I simply minimize the entire VS window, then restore it. Poof! My properties appear. Trivial, but painful.

Answer (score 0):

1 Make sure that your build program is not running (use task manager to end that process if needed) and make sure that you can rebuild your project without errors.
2 Restart Visual Studio as an Administrator.
Good Luck For You All ^_^

Comment: You should not suggest people to run VS as Administrator. It is not recommanded and should be reserved only for specific tasks : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/user-permissions-and-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: I don't see anywhere on your link that says it is not recommended. It just says you can run VS as a typical user, most of the time.

Comment: @Alan The first sentence of that page says, "For reasons of security, you should run Visual Studio as a typical user whenever possible."

Comment: @BimmerM3 Yes, it does say that. But there have been occasions when I had to run VS as administrator because of some permissions that my app required. However, I have never experienced any issues as a result of running as admin. I would like to know about these reasons of security that they speak of.

Answer (score 0):

I manually edited .csprj file and removed all entries related with [file].json, saved and the file's properties are now showing

Answer (score 0):

As IVanF. states in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76780241/9541862) above, I too experience this issue when I accidentally double click in the 'Build Action' option within the 'Properties' pane. For me the file type is a .cshtml file.

[image]

**The easiest solution I've found is to exclude the file and then include the file.**

1. Right click the file and select 'Exclude From Project' .
2. Enable 'Show All Files' at the top of the Solution Explorer.
3. Right click the file again and then select 'Include In Project'
4. Reset the properties as needed for the 'Copy to Output Directory' and 'Build Action' as they will return to the default values which may not be wanted if it's a .cshtml file

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue for ages where properties wouldn't populate, properties finally populated after I had opened the VS app as admin. - Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

This just started happening to me in VS2022. I know I'm coming late to the question, but it's the most recent I could find.

In any case, I took a guess, deleted the .csproj.user file, and restarted VS. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with properties window not updating when in view designer window.

It sometimes will not populate the properties window with the data of the object you have clicked on in the design view. To fix this I right click the .cs file in the Solution Explorer and change to view code, then right click again and select view designer and poof like magic the properties window start working again.

Answer (score -1):

I have just encountered this error and it was simply solved by closing the visual studio and reopening it again. it is just gone.