# Visual Studio: Project Properties Blank, Not Creating .csproj File

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2022

I am writing a `C++` project in Visual Studio. I used the `CMake` template.

[image]

I then want to go to the Project Properties, but it is blank.

[image]

I saw that other people had been having this problem, and one suggested solution was to delete the `.csproj` file; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78069018/5065462. However, I don't seem to have a `.csproj` file—or a `.sln` file, or anything like that.

[image]

If I click `File --> Open --> Project/Solution (Ctrl+Shift+O)` to open a project and navigate to the folder, then no project files exist.

[image]

My primary desire is to get access to the Project Properties, but it seems that I need a Project File to do this.

Answer (score 3):

csproj is for C# project. vcxproj is for C++.

vcxproj  file is not needed   in cmake project.

If you want to create .vcxproj file, right click test folder -> open in terminal -> input command `cmake .` And it will generate solution and `test` project

[image]

If you are learning to use C++, you should create from Console App template.

[image]

Comment: +1 I see, thank you. Running `cmake .` created a whole host of files. In particular, it created `ALL_BUILD` and `ZERO_CHECK`. When I open the project, via `Test.vcxproj` or `.sln`, it is unable to run (but can build), saying that the file in `ALL_BUILD` doesn't exist. I can get around this by right-clicking "Set as Startup Project", but I'm not sure if this is the correct thing to do?—or, what the three different `.vcxproj` files are for

Comment: ***saying that the file in ALL_BUILD doesn't exist.*** ALL_BUILD is not a runnable project so if you tried to run it, that is your error. Switch to a target that is an application that can be run.

Comment: @user24601  Click the sln file to open in Visual Studio -> right click your C++ project (The project whose name is not ALL_Build or Zero_check. In your screenshot is project `test`) ->    set as startup project. Then click the green triangle to run.